# How to make a RESTful call using Basic Authentication in apache camel?

Tags: rest, authentication, https, apache-camel

I have an apache camel application that requires sending log files to an endpoint and this requires Basic Authentication. I was able to pass the authMethod, authusername and authPassword to the url as specified in the camel documentation but the challange I'm having is that I keep getting null response from the endpoint after starting the application. 
However, the same endpoint returns response code and response body using postman.

Below is my code:

```
from("{{routes.feeds.working.directory}}?idempotent=true")
                .process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
                    multipartEntityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                    String fileName = exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, String.class);
                    File file = exchange.getIn().getBody(File.class);
                    multipartEntityBuilder.addPart("file",
                            new FileBody(file, ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, fileName));
                    exchange.getOut().setBody(multipartEntityBuilder.build());
                    Message out = exchange.getOut();
                    int responseCode = out.getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, Integer.class);
                    log.info("response code "+responseCode);

            }
        })
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, 
            constant("authMethod=Basic&authUsername="+username+"&authPassword="+password+""))
                .to(TARGET_WITH_AUTH +"/"+uuid+"/files")
                .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "response code >>>>"+Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE)
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "RESPONSE BODY ${body}")
                .end();
```

Kindly help review and advise further

Comment: What was HTTP response code?

Comment: @Rajkumar Now I'm getting 401 "unauthorized" response code. Whereas I get 200 response code using postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by using httpClient to send my requests with Basic Authentication. Apparently, `authMethod` in apache camel doesn't send the credentials along with the Post Request  and that's why I was getting the initial 401 response code.
Thank y'all for your contributions.

Answer (score 0):

For HTTP basic authentication I use this before sending a request

```
<setHeader headerName="Authorization">
    <constant>Basic cm9vdDpyb290</constant>
</setHeader>
```

cm9vdDpyb290 - Encoded Base64 root:root(username and password) string

Comment: I have tried setting the Authorization header with the encoded credentials and it returned reponse code 400

Comment: What I tried recently was to add RAW syntax to my password because the password contains special characters. I still got 401 after sending the plain password

Comment: 400 Error code means, credential are valid but something wrong with payload.